# Python tokenize: token position

Tags: python, tokenize

Python's tokenize returns all the found tokens' position as two tuples of (startRow, startCol) and (endRow, endCol).

Is there a way to return the positions as the offsets from the beginning of the string? That is, I would like to get rid of (row, col) in favor of just "offset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one built-in to `tokenize`.

If you had access to the same set of lines being used by the tokenizer, you could run through and store the accumulated "total length of lines before line X" into a list, and then use that to convert the row values into additive offsets.

For instance:

```
import tokenize

def tokens_with_offset(path):
    line_offsets = []
    line_offset_accum = 0
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            line_offsets.append(line_offset_accum)
            line_offset_accum += len(line)

    with open(path) as f:
        for ttype, tstring, tbegin, tend, tline in tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline):
            offset_begin = line_offsets[tbegin[0]] + tbegin[1]
            offset_end = line_offsets[tend[0]] + tend[1]
            yield ttype, tstring, offset_begin, offset_end, tline
```

(Note: haven't tested this code, it's more as an example of the general concept.)

Comment: To process the text twice is a no-go for me, but I accepted the answer as I was asking for specifically about tokenize. If you could think of a way to make it return offsets without the preprocessing, I would be thankful if you posted it here.

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily have to process it twice - you could create a wrapper around the file that records the line offsets as it's being read in the first place (and then passes the line on to generate_tokens). It was just easier to write the example with a 2-pass process. :)

Comment: But `generate_tokens` does not returns the lines being processed. So you would have to somehow figure out that you advanced to next line and add the length line to the offset, right? That is, you have to find the line breaks twice - once in `generate_tokens` and other time in this offset accumulator.

Comment: No - you wrap the thing that you pass *in* to `generate_tokens` as its input source. `generate_tokens` requires an object that has a `.readline()` function. You can create such an object that has an internal counter the basically uses the same code as the first loop in my 2-pass example.